# Can't solve linker error for small C program on CentOS 8.1

Tags: c, gnu-make

I'm getting a linker error when I try to build a small C program on CentOS 8.1.  I'm new to Linux development, and to using make, and I haven't been able to solve the error.  The linker is failing to resolve a function that's defined in a static library.  I built the static library from the sample code for the APUE book.

I'm able to build my program, if I use a makefile that's provided with the APUE sample code.  But I'm trying to get it to build with a simpler makefile that I wrote.

The program is:

```
#include "apue.h"

int
main(void)
{
    err_exit(8, "hello world");
    exit(0);
}
```

The relevant line from the header file is:

```
void    err_exit(int, const char *, ...) __attribute__((noreturn));
```

The makefile is:

```
runme: testprog.o
    gcc -ansi -Wall -o runme -L. -lapue testprog.o

testprog.o: testprog.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -o testprog.o -I. -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE testprog.c
```

The error is:

$ make
gcc -ansi -Wall -o runme -L. -lapue testprog.o
testprog.o: In function `main':
testprog.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to`err_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2: runme] Error 1

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: move `-lapue` after `testprog.o`.

Comment: Yes thanks that worked